# For the straight line between points with position vectors a and b, find an explicit unit-speed parameterization.

Tags: vectors, curvature, arc-length

this is my first time posting here. I am not sure how to type everything so please forgive my notation.

I have the following question and I have worked throught it most of the way, there is just one step that I am not sure on and cannot proceed until I know I have done it right.

So, I started out with the following parameterization for the line: **X**(t) = **a** + t(**b**-**a**)

My first step was to follow through with an arc length parameterization. I used the formula

S(t) = The integral from t0 up to t of the magnitude of X'(t) with respect to t.

I found x'(t) to be b-a and therefore the magnitude is just |b-a|. However, my concern is in taking there integral of this.

Is it just t|b-a|? I am confused because this is more or less where I am started with the exception of the magnitude.

I know that after I find S(t), I will invert the function to get something in the form t(s) = something and that will be the unit speed parameterization I am looking for.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: the integral of some scalar valued function along this path would be $\int_0^1 f(t) \|\mathbf b-\mathbf a\| \ dt$

Comment: In this case f(t) is x(t)?? Also why is it from 0 to 1? So I am looking at a + t(b-a) |b-a| dt?

Comment: $0$ to $1,$ because  $\mathbf x(0)= \mathbf a,$ and $\mathbf x(1) = \mathbf b$ as for what is $f(t)$ that depends on what you are trying to measure (or integrate).  If you just what the lenght of the segment $f(t) = 1$ and or $f(t)$ could be a measure of force, (or altitude) and the integral would be energy (or area).

Answer (score 1):

You have for the length $S=\int_0^t\|\mathbf b-\mathbf a\|du=\|\mathbf b-\mathbf a\|t$.

So $t=\frac{S}{\|\mathbf b-\mathbf a\|}$ hence
your arc-parametrization is
$$X(S)=\mathbf a+\frac{S}{\|\mathbf b-\mathbf a\|}(\mathbf b-\mathbf a).$$
The range for $S$ is $0\le S\le \|\mathbf b-\mathbf a\|$, since
$X(0)=\mathbf a$ and $X(\|\mathbf b-\mathbf a\|)=\mathbf b$.

It is easy to see that $\|\frac{dX}{dS}\|=1$.